# Travelling Salesman with latitude/longitude coordinates?

Tags: maps, traveling-salesman

Travelling Salesman with latitude/longitude coordinates?

I am reading about many heuristics for the TSP and many use Euclidian x/y coordinates.
But I have my data as latitude and longitude, so how do I use those heuristics?
That is, is there a meaningful way to go from latitude/longitude to x/y coordinates?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the score function, you can just use Pythagoras directly on the latitude and longitude to calculate the distance between 2 points.

To visualize it in a panel with a specific width and height, take a look at my [LatitudeLongitudeTranslator](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/optaplanner/blob/master/optaplanner-examples/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/examples/common/swingui/latitudelongitude/LatitudeLongitudeTranslator.java) (java, open source, ASL 2.0) which is used in this [TSP GUI](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/optaplanner/blob/master/optaplanner-examples/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/examples/tsp/swingui/TspWorldPanel.java).

Comment: It's a little bit dangerous to use degrees directly in the Pythagoras theorem as its mapping to meters is not linear. I could agree that for some problems it's a (very fast) good-enough approach, but if you need precision, that's certainly not the way to go.

Comment: @psousa Agreed that the curving of the earth has an effect. However, many TSP datasets specify `EDGE_WEIGHT_TYPE : EUC_2D` which means you *must* ignore the curving and use Pythagoras. So it depends on the dataset.